# Execute async request inside .map loop in correct order

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, request-promise, array.prototype.map

I'm struggling with .map loop and async function inside. I use request-promise for async requests.

```
  import * as rp from 'request-promise';

  const testArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
  const link = 'https://somelink.com/';

  const test = testArray.map(async (elem) => {
    console.log('before', elem);

    await rp.get(link)
      .then(async () => {
        console.log('success');
      });

    console.log('after', elem);
  });

  Promise.all(test);
```

The output of this code:

```
before one
before two
before three
success
after one
success
after three
success
after two
```

What I need is that the code to execute in the correct order with output like this:

```
before one
success
after one
before two
success
after two
before three
success
after three
```

Can't figure out what am I doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: `Promise.all` will give you the results in order,  but your not either returning anything in your map, and not using the results from`Promise.all` too.  Like jfriend says for serial execution `for of` would be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.map()` is NOT `async` aware.  It will not pause its loop for an `await` in the callback function you pass it.  Instead, the `await` will just immediately cause the `async` function to return an unresolved promise and the `.map()` will go right ahead with the other iterations of the loop.  As you already seem to know the resulting array from `.map()` will just be an array of those promises.

If you want the loop to pause and wait for the `await`, so you can truly sequence your asynchronous operations, then use a plain `for` loop, not a `.map()` loop.

```
 import * as rp from 'request-promise';

  const testArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
  const link = 'https://somelink.com/';

  for (let elem of testArray) {
    console.log('before', elem);

    await rp.get(link)
      .then(async () => {
        console.log('success', elem);
      });

    console.log('after', elem);
  });
```

This will then execute your `rp.get()` operations in sequence waiting for the first one to complete before the second one is executed.  Your `.map()` loop was executing them all in parallel which means you do not control the order of execution.

---

FYI, the `request()` library and the corresponding derivatives of it have been deprecated and will no longer be actively developed to add new features.  There is a list of alternatives [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) that are recommended for all new projects.  My favorite is [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) which was built from the ground up to use promises, but you can pick whichever one has the features you want and/or an API you like.

Comment: Thanks! It works! But is there any replacement of "for...of" loop? Because my eslint throws no-restricted-syntax error

Comment: @tjnk24 - Why is eslint complaining about a `for/of` loop?  Perhaps want to fix your eslint settings.  That is modern JS syntax.  You can use an old-fashioned for loop if you want `for (let i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) { ... }` and then refer to `testArray[i]` in the loop, but `for/of` is a newer and better way to program.